How to update the project build date and time in the bin file header without make clean and full build
I am using ESP IDF version 5.3.
If I do a make clean and full build, the build date and time is updated in my project where I reference DATE and TIME as well as in the project bin file header.
But if I don't do a full build, the build date and time do not update.
I know which file I need to "touch" in MY source so that my app always gets the new build, but the binary file header referenced by OTA does not update. I have also confirmed this with a binary file viewer, see below staring at address 0000:0000
e9 05 02 4f b4 55 37 40 ee 00 00 00 09 00 00 00
00 63 00 00 00 00 00 01 20 00 13 3c 1c e3 04 00
32 54 cd ab 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
31 2e 31 2e 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
77 69 6e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
31 33 3a 31 35 3a 30 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      33:15:00
53 65 70 20 33 30 20 32 30 32 34 00 00 00 00 00      Sep 30 2024
76 35 2e 33 2d 64 69 72 74 79 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

I am using OTA via HTTPS and am referencing the bin file header build date and time so I need this to be correct for management purposes.
I have seen articles suggesting I need to touch the file ../esp/v5.3/esp-idf/components/app_update/esp_ota_app_desc.c, but I have not found this to make any difference to any references to the build date and time which appear in the header or anywhere else for that matter.
